# Rails DateTime a certain hour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In Rails, is it possibly to have `DateTime.now` at 9am an onwards?

I'm looking to have a date range, but I want the data to display only if it's at/after 9am.

```
(1.day.ago.to_date.at_midnight-3.hours)..(DateTime.now.at_midnight-3.hours)
```

So something like this will give me the data from 9am the previous day to the current day at 9am, then resets.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for

```
DateTime.now.beginning_of_day + 9.hours
```